# ElasticSearch Spring criteriaquery boolean field

Tags: elasticsearch

We are migrating from Mongo DB to ElasticSearch.

In MongoDB, we have got the below query for Boolean field existence;

Criteria.where("field-name").exists(true) ;

what is the equivalent query for elastic search using spring elastic search criteria

How do i search for boolean field in elastic search

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use exists filter. You should have a look here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html